# Element::after - Overlay

Tags: css, overlay, pseudo-element

I am currently trying something. I would like to create a partial overlay, using the pseudo-element of the parent-div. This is not the problem. I solved it, but the thing is, that the pseudo-element is also over the section below the header.

Just follow the link, to get to my

```
    codepen.io/enrico1337/pen/xaeZMP
```

I would really appreciate it, if someone has a solution so the overlay is only visible inside the header and does not overshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the content to flow over the next section you can use `overflow: hidden` on the header.

> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. No scrollbars are provided.
>   scroll

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #ffffff;
}

header {
  padding: 7em;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532274402911-5a369e4c4bb5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=81a5f1725ca68c549e0054dcfdf269de&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: calc(100vh - 14em);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .8;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0, -7deg) translateY(380px);
          transform: skew(0, -7deg) translateY(380px);
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 5.5em;
  position: absolute;
}
header p {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 16em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  line-height: 1.7;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
}
#wrapper p {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding-right: 16em;
  line-height: 1.7;
}
#wrapper section {
  padding: 9em 7em;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: calc(100% - 14em);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Awesome Landscapes</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Also put `position: relative` to your header if you want the content inside it to be positioned relatively to the header.